# SQL Server 2012 Aggregate on Split Date Time?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, aggregate-functions

I have data that looks like the below. The first table has a column for date and two columns to represent a one-hour window of time. The second table has datetime and information that needs to be aggregated and matched to fit the apporpriate window.

```
declare @timetable table ( dateutc datetime , timestart time , timeend time )
insert into @timetable
select '2013-06-02 00:00:00.000' , '14:00:00.0000000' , '15:00:00.0000000' 
union all select  '2013-06-02 00:00:00.000' , '13:00:00.0000000' , '14:00:00.0000000' 
union all select '2013-06-02 00:00:00.000' , '12:00:00.0000000' , '13:00:00.0000000' 
union all select  '2013-06-02 00:00:00.000' , '11:00:00.0000000' , '12:00:00.0000000' 


declare @actiontable table ( datetimeutc datetime , parentid int , actioncount int )
insert into @actiontable 
select '2013-06-02 12:56:01.403' , 3 , 1
union all select '2013-06-02 13:15:00.000' , 3 , 1
union all select '2013-06-02 13:14:01.453' , 3 , 1
union all select '2013-06-02 13:14:01.363' , 4 , 2
union all select '2013-06-02 14:00:07.006' , 4 , 2
union all select '2013-06-02 14:00:07.006' , 4 , 2
union all select '2013-06-02 14:00:07.006' , 5 , 1
union all select '2013-06-02 15:16:01.403' , 5 , 1
union all select '2013-06-02 15:16:01.403' , 5 , 1
union all select '2013-06-02 15:16:01.403' , 5 , 2
```

I am lost on how to "join" the sets of data to make it look like the below. All ideas/help appreciated.

Thanks!

```
/*
dateutc , timestart , timeend ,  actioncount 
2013-06-02 00:00:00.000 , 14:00:00.0000000 ,    15:00:00.0000000 , 9
2013-06-02 00:00:00.000 , 13:00:00.0000000 ,    14:00:00.0000000 , 4
2013-06-02 00:00:00.000 , 12:00:00.0000000 ,    13:00:00.0000000 , 1
2013-06-02 00:00:00.000 , 11:00:00.0000000 ,    12:00:00.0000000 , 0
*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t.dateutc, t.timestart, t.timeend, ISNULL(SUM(A.actioncount), 0)
FROM
    @timetable T
    LEFT JOIN
    @actiontable A ON t.dateutc + CAST(t.timestart AS datetime) <= A.datetimeutc AND A.datetimeutc < T.dateutc + CAST(t.timeend AS datetime)
GROUP BY
    t.dateutc, t.timestart, t.timeend
ORDER BY
    t.dateutc DESC, t.timestart DESC;
```

Comment: you are right, cast is needed. I have tested it ... but in sqlfiddle without change to sqlserver2012!

Comment: This answer is pure hotness. Thanks!